# Owin Windows Forms / Reset Passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-identity

I am trying to work out how to send reset password links from a windows forms application which then work within an ASP.NET MVC 5 website.  I am currently using Microsoft.OWIN Identity as the authentication provider.  I am able to create users, but whenever I try to send a token, the website always states that it is invalid, does any one have any idea how I need to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: I can do it through forcing the dataProtectionPRovider to be the DpapiDataProtectionProvider - when the web app starts it creates a different provider which evidentially is why the tokens are never accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to use the DpapiDataProtectionProvider is for both parties, the web and win forms processes, to share the same machine key, and the web site to share the same process model. Not likely to pull that off!

Instead, could you use a webapi request so the web site can produce the token, with all proper authentication for the win forms app, and then the win forms app just sends it in it's way?

Comment: This is a good answer.  If you leave responsibility for token generation entirely within the web app, then the system as a whole is easier to reason about.  In particular, the DPAPI provider isn't recommended for anything other than development scenarios.